# Using Wired Property in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have defined an Apex Controller

```
public inherited sharing class ListCont {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Map<String, String>> getOptions(String sobjectName, String fieldName) {
    return new List<Map<String, String>>{new Map<String,String>{'value'=>'x','label'=>'x x'}};
} 
}
```

and LWC Html file

```
<template>
    <template for:each={options} for:item="o">
        <li key={o.value}>
            {o.value}, {o.label}
        </li>
    </template>
</template>
```

and Javascript module

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getOptions from '@salesforce/apex/ListCont.getOptions';
export default class List extends LightningElement {
@wire(getOptions, {sobjectName:'Account', fieldName:'AccountSource'})
options/* = [
    { label: 'Y Y y', value: 'yyy' }
]*/;
```

and it doesn't work, with Lightning Debug Mode enabled, it generates error

> afterRender threw an error in 'c:list' [Assert Violation: Invalid
>   template iteration for value `[object Object]` in [object:vm undefined
>   (45)], it requires an array-like object, not `null` or `undefined`.]
>   [[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXP8S.png)

Without Lightning Debug Mode, it generates error

> afterRender threw an error in 'c:list' [e[ki] is not a function]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For wired property usage, `.data` property of returned result should be used.

Also, it is good practice to surround code which displays these data with `<template if:true={options.data}>` tag to avoid displaying anything if data is not set.

So final working code looks like following

```
<template if:true={options.data}>
    <template for:each={options.data} for:item="o">
        <li key={o.value}>
            {o.value}, {o.label}
        </li>
    </template>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please accept this answer to close the question?

Comment: yes, sure. Done.